# Flash AS3-XML Gallery compile errors

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript

```
package  {

import flash.display.*;          
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;


public class gallery extends MovieClip {


    public function gallery() {
        // constructor code


            var columns:Number;
            var my_x:Number;
            var my_y:Number;
            var my_thumb_width:Number;
            var my_thumb_height:Number;
            var my_images:XMLList;
            var my_total:Number;

            var container_mc:MovieClip;
            var preloaders_mc:MovieClip;
            var full_mc:MovieClip;

            var x_counter:Number = 0;
            var y_counter:Number = 0;

            var my_tweens:Array = [];
            var container_mc_tween:Tween;
            var full_tween:Tween;

            var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("gallery.xml"));
            myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

            function processXML(e:Event):void {
                var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

                columns = myXML.@COLUMNS;
                my_x = myXML.@XPOSITION;
                my_y = myXML.@YPOSITION;
                my_thumb_width = myXML.@WIDTH;
                my_thumb_height = myXML.@HEIGHT;
                my_images = myXML.IMAGE;
                my_total = my_images.length();

                createContainer();
                callThumbs();

                myXMLLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
                myXMLLoader = null;
            }

            function createContainer():void {
                container_mc = new MovieClip();
                container_mc.x = my_x;
                container_mc.y = my_y;
                addChild(container_mc);

                container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFull);
                container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver);
                container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);
                container_mc.buttonMode = true;

                preloaders_mc = new MovieClip();
                preloaders_mc.x = container_mc.x;
                preloaders_mc.y = container_mc.y;
                addChild(preloaders_mc);
            }

            function callThumbs():void {
                for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++) {

                    var thumb_url = my_images[i].@THUMB;

                    var thumb_loader = new Loader();
                    thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
                    thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);

                    thumb_loader.name = i;

                    thumb_loader.x = (my_thumb_width+10)*x_counter;
                    thumb_loader.y = (my_thumb_height+10)*y_counter;

                    if (x_counter+1 < columns) {
                        x_counter++;
                    } else {
                        x_counter = 0;
                        y_counter++;
                    }
                    var preloader_pb:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
                    preloader_pb.source = thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo;
                    preloader_pb.x = thumb_loader.x;
                    preloader_pb.y = thumb_loader.y;
                    preloader_pb.width = my_thumb_width;
                    preloader_pb.height = my_thumb_height;
                    preloaders_mc.addChild(preloader_pb);

                    preloader_pb.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, donePb);
                }
            }

            function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void {
                var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
                container_mc.addChild(my_thumb);
                my_tweens[Number(my_thumb.name)]=new Tween(my_thumb, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);

                my_thumb.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);
            }

            function callFull(e:MouseEvent):void {
                var full_loader:Loader = new Loader();
                var full_url = my_images[e.target.name].@FULL;
                full_loader.load(new URLRequest(full_url));
                full_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, fullLoaded);

                var full_pb:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
                full_pb.source = full_loader.contentLoaderInfo;
                full_pb.x = (stage.stageWidth - full_pb.width)/2;
                full_pb.y = (stage.stageHeight - full_pb.height)/2;
                preloaders_mc.addChild(full_pb);

                full_pb.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, donePb);

                container_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFull);
                container_mc.buttonMode = false;
                container_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver);
                container_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);
                container_mc_tween = new Tween(container_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 1,0.5,0.5, true);
            }
            function fullLoaded(e:Event):void {
                full_mc = new MovieClip();
                full_mc.buttonMode = true;
                addChild(full_mc);
                var my_loader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
                full_mc.addChild(my_loader);
                full_tween = new Tween(my_loader, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);
                my_loader.x = (stage.stageWidth - my_loader.width)/2;
                my_loader.y = (stage.stageHeight - my_loader.height)/2;
                my_loader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,removeFull);

                my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fullLoaded);
            }
            function removeFull(e:MouseEvent):void {
                var my_loader:Loader = Loader (e.currentTarget);
                full_tween = new Tween(my_loader, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1,0,0.5, true);
                full_tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, tweenFinished);

                container_mc_tween = new Tween(container_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0.5,1,0.5, true);
            }

            function donePb(e:Event):void {
                var my_pb:ProgressBar = ProgressBar(e.target);
                preloaders_mc.removeChild(my_pb);
                my_pb.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, donePb);
            }

            function tweenFinished(e:TweenEvent):void {
                var my_loader:Loader = Loader (e.target.obj);
                my_loader.unload();
                full_mc.removeChild(my_loader);// This line was removeChid(my_loader), just add full_mc before it.
                removeChild(full_mc);
                full_mc = null;

                container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFull);
                container_mc.buttonMode = true;
                container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver);
                container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);

                var my_tween:Tween = Tween(e.target);
                my_tween.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, tweenFinished);
            }
            function onOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
                var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target);
                my_thumb.alpha = 0.5;
            }
            function onOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
                var my_thumb:Loader = Loader (e.target);
                my_thumb.alpha = 1;
            }
          }
       }
   }
```

**I got these errors, and probably more after those:

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ProgressBar.

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method ProgressBar.

thanks in progress**

Answer (score 0):

These Errors Occurred because there is no progress bar component into your library.
Drag and Drop the Progress Bar Component on stage and then Delete from stage if you don't required on stage.In this way an instance of progress bar component is created into library.